# How can we reduce jar file size generated from maven-assembly-plugin ? With only 2 dependencies my jar file size is 91 mb

Tags: maven, pom.xml, maven-plugin

I am generating jar with dependencies and the file size I am getting is 110,405 kb which is huge... I have only 2 dependencies in my pom.xml i.e.

1. ApacheJMeter_Java
2. Selenium Java

Is there any way to reduce the jar file size?

Comment: Have you unpacked the jar and had a look what makes it so large?

Comment: The 2 dependencies in your POM have (transitive) dependencies themselves and these transitive dependencies have again (transitive) dependencies. Look what you get if you perform `mvn dependency:tree` on your project.